# Create your original sequence challenge

Tags: code-golf, internet

There are lots of challenges that just pick a sequence from oeis and ask you to print n-th number or first n numbers or whatever.

It's time to <s>stop</s> automate!

### Task

Your task is to parse a sequence page from [oeis.org](http://oeis.org/) and print its index, description and example values. The page's index should be chosen and random, selected uniformly from the range `[1-289361]`.

Example outputs (formatted with newline as a separator):

```
A034434
Multiplicity of highest weight (or singular) vectors associated with character chi_46 of Monster module.
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 7, 12, 21, 38, 60, 102, 165, 265, 416, 660, 1015, 1574, 2405, 3665, 5535, 8364, 12512, 18726, 27862, 41391, 61240, 90541, 133381, 196395, 288534, 423656, 621219, 910885, 1334634

A38246
Triangle whose (i,j)-th entry is binomial(i,j)*5^(i-j)*4^j.
1, 5, 4, 25, 40, 16, 125, 300, 240, 64, 625, 2000, 2400, 1280, 256, 3125, 12500, 20000, 16000, 6400, 1024, 15625, 75000, 150000, 160000, 96000, 30720, 4096, 78125, 437500, 1050000, 1400000, 1120000, 537600, 143360, 16384, 390625

A212813
Number of steps for n to reach 8 under iteration of the map i -&gt; <a href="/A036288" title="a(n) = 1 + integer log of n: if the prime factorization of n is n = Product (p_j^k_j) then a(n) = 1 + Sum (p_j * k_j) (cf. A...">A036288</a>(i), or -1 if 8 is never reached.
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 3, 6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4

A155181
a(n)=5*a(n-1)+a(n-2), n&gt;2 ; a(0)=1, a(1)=4, a(2)=20 .
1, 4, 20, 104, 540, 2804, 14560, 75604, 392580, 2038504, 10585100, 54964004, 285405120, 1481989604, 7695353140, 39958755304, 207489129660, 1077404403604, 5594511147680, 29049960142004, 150844311857700, 783271519430504

A227356
Partial sums of <a href="/A129361" title="a(n) = sum{k=floor((n+1)/2)..n, F(k+1)}.">A129361</a>.
1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 36, 65, 112, 193, 324, 544, 900, 1489, 2442, 4005, 6534, 10660, 17336, 28193, 45760, 74273, 120408, 195200, 316216, 512257, 829458, 1343077, 2174130, 3519412, 5696124, 9219105, 14919408, 24144289
```

Example, ungolfed, python script:

```
import requests
import random
seq = 'A%s' % `random.randint(1,289361)`.zfill(6)
page = requests.get('http://oeis.org/%s' % seq)
print_next = False
content = []
for line in page.text.split('\n'):
    if print_next:
        print_next = False
        content.append(line)
    if '<td width="710' in line or '<td valign=top align=left>' in line:
        print_next = True
print seq
print content[0].lstrip()
print content[1].lstrip()[4:-5]
```

### Rules

- [oeis.org](http://oeis.org/) states, that there are **289361** sequences right now. You should not try to parse pages with higher index.
- Your program should **uniformly** choose a random page.
- Your program may produced undefined behavior if it randomly chooses to parse an oeis page that is reserved or does not contain a sequence (see [A288145](http://oeis.org/A288145))
- Trailing white space is acceptable.
- You must remove leading white space and the outermost html tags from each line of your output. (i.e., the example values are wrapped in `<tt><tt/>`, which must be removed, but the description sometimes contains tags such as `<href>` within the text. Such tags do not need to be handled (see [A195534](http://oeis.org/A219225))).
- You do not have to handle html escapes (see [A219225](http://oeis.org/A219225))
- You do not need to print leading zeroes in the index. (e.g. A1 and A000001 are both acceptable). This is because [oeis.org](http://oeis.org/) itself allows you to do either, as in, http://oeis.org/A1 and http://oeis.org/A000001 are both valid URLs that point to the same page.
- You may return/print the "lines" in one of the following formats:

  - As an array/list with three elements
  - As a string separated by some separator. However, the separator **must not appear** in any of the "lines" (the index, the description, or the example values). In addition, this separator must be consistent (you can't select a separator based on the content of the "lines").
- The [meta definition of uniformly random](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10923/56085) applies.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: [Very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89376/automate-the-oeis)

Comment: @WheatWizard Yep. But task is different

Comment: This needs to specify precisely what formats are permitted and deal with edge cases including particularly gaps in the sequence IDs (e.g. http://oeis.org/A288145 )

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think, that edits made to post are specify it all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CJam (61 bytes)

```
"oeis.org/search?fmt=text&q=id:A"289361mr)s+gN%{1=s"ISN"&},N*
```

No online demo available because the use of `g` is restricted by both online testers for security reasons.

I'm still not convinced that the output format is clearly specified, but since I seem to be in a minority I'm exploiting its gaps for golfiness. There is no leading whitespace or outer HTML tag to remove in the output.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 198 bytes

```
from requests import*
import random,html
s='A%s'%str(random.randint(1,289355))
print(s)
t=get('http://oeis.org/%s'%s).text.split('\n')
print(html.unescape(t[95].strip()))
print(t[116].strip()[4:-5])
```

This works for everything I've tried so far, but since it hard-codes the line indices, please tell me if it breaks on anything (that isn't an unfilled reserved spot).

-9 bytes thanks to Dead Possum

Comment: You may remove `.zfill(6)`. Turns out, that leading zeros are not necessary

Comment: @DeadPossum Oh cool, thanks.